# Sorting right-to-left order on a multicolumn table in bash

Tags: bash, sorting

I want to sort a file of the following format using the `sort` command in bash in which the letters A to C should be sorted in suffix order.

```
Value1 C B C Value2
Value1 A B C Value2 
Value1 C C A Value2
```

The desired output is:

```
Value1 C C A Value2
Value1 A B C Value2 
Value1 C B C Value2
```

Until now I've only found how to sort the 2nd, then 3rd and then 4th column with the command `sort -k 2,4 file_name.txt`. How can I sort the columns in the reverse order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sort -k 4,4 -k 3,3 -k 2,2 file
```

Output:

```
Value1 C C A Value2
Value1 A B C Value2 
Value1 C B C Value2
```